If someone at their deathbed feels like they lived a good enough life & don't need anything anymore, does it mean they ceased craving & became Buddhas
If someone at their deathbed feels like they lived a good enough life and don't need anything anymore, then they ceased carving right? Did they become Buddhas? Their last mindstream's moment will not be conditioned by craving, so no rebirth right?

It might appear that the craving for sensual pleasure is gone because one had a good enough life. But it could just be temporarily satiated. A more subtle craving or hunger may then manifest, i.e. the craving for existence. It may not be obvious at the level of normal consciousness as it usually lurks in the subconscious. Often, this hunger only reveal itself in the aftermath of a deep meditation when the mind is surveyed while it is drenched in stillness.
At this point, the mind could be in a state of ease, contentment and stillness. If we are quick, alert and dispassionate enough, we might catch a tiny part of the mind still asking, “what’s next”; searching and wanting for more. But more what? More ease, relaxation, comfort and pleasantness. It may seem ironical but the argument put forth is impeccable. Afterall, what’s wrong or bad about existing if it is pleasant and wonderful? Right view, if it is present, would immediately point out that it is still anatta and anicca. Thus, it will eventually turn into unpleasantness and suffering.
At this point, the mind may recoil, become disgusted and repulsed; giving rise to another craving i.e. the desire for non-existence. Which is why I find the path to be complex, it is like peeling an onion. Maybe, this is also because the mind is really complicated.
